# Dynamic Dashboard for Summary statistics and graphs for selected/all variables drop down of a DF in R

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am new to R and want to make a dashboard in R which shows all the data and summary statistics, Histograms and boxplots for all variables or selected variables from a data imported from a location/drive or from a DB which has a browse button or connect button in that page displayed. I need the R code for connecting to any DB too, I know how to connect to MySQL server through R but I need it to connect to any database. Any resources related to Shiny/Dynamic pages in R would greatly help.
  **Here the code I tried which has those 2 errors**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)


## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(

    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Dashboard For Data Analysis"),

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

      # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
      sidebarPanel(

        # Input: Select a file ----
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")),
        # Horizontal line ----
        tags$hr(),

        # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
        radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                     choices = c(Head = "head",
                                 All = "all"),
                     selected = "head"),

        # Horizontal line ----
        tags$hr()
        # Select Variable from the selected Dataset 

        selectInput("vari", "Variable", 
                    choices=colnames(df),

                    hr(),
                    helpText("")  


        ),  

        ########################## 

        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(

          # Output: Data file ----
          h1("Overview of the Data")
          DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
          h2("Summary Statistics")
          verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
          plotOutput('plot')
        )  
      )
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session){
      myData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        data123 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
      })

      output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(myData())       
      })
      output$select <- renderUI({
        df <- myData()
        selectInput("variable", "Select Variables:",names(df))

      })

      output$summary <- renderPrint({
        df <- myData()
        df <- df[,input$variable]
        summary(df) 
      })

      output$summary <- renderPrint({
        df <- myData()
        df <- df[,input$variable]
        describe(df) 
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        df <- myData()
        df <- df[,input$variable]
        boxplot(df,col="sky blue",border="purple",main= 'Boxplot of 'input$variable)
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui,server)
}
```

Comment: You can take a look in here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#data

Comment: Thank you @Subhasish, I did started working from that site.

Comment: Hi guys, I have made something in Shiny-- But it gives the error as Error-need finite 'ylim' values and Error-number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.Can you have a look into my code??

Comment: Also I couldn't see the describe block of the data??

Comment: Also I need something to differentiate between Numeric Vars and factor vars and generate correlation adn Histograms on the page

Comment: Hi,
is it me or I didn't get where occur the two errors you are talking about?

Comment: Hey Elie, here are the ones

Comment: Error-need finite 'ylim' values and Error-number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.